# Generating a table of unique substrings in R

Tags: r, unique, substr

So I have a very large dataset and I want to know the unique values for a column that has about 400,000 observations and each one looks like this:
`identifier:abzcd:def:RANDOMNUMBERSTRING` and `identifier:de:ghijklm:RANDOMNUMBERSTRING`.
I want only unique matches for the section before the random number string. In other words, I only want to filter out duplicates for the code: `identifier:LETTERS:LETTERS`
The `unique` function doesn't work and it looks like I need to know exactly what substrings I want to filter or how long the substrings are to use the `substr` function. Any suggestions about how I can do this?

Below is some data that can be used as a model:

```
randz <- data.frame(id =
                      sprintf("identifier:%s%s%s:%s%s%s:%s",
                 sample(letters, 1000,replace = T ),
                 sample(letters, 1000,replace = T ),
                 sample(letters, 1000,replace = T ),
                 sample(letters, 1000,replace = T ),
                 sample(letters, 1000,replace = T ),
                 sample(letters, 1000,replace = T ),
                 sample(6000:7000, 1000, replace = T )))
randz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one simple approach using the `tidyverse`

```
# Fake Data
randz <- data.frame(id =
                      sprintf("identifier:%s%s%s:%s%s%s:%s",
                 sample(letters, 1000,replace = T ),
                 sample(letters, 1000,replace = T ),
                 sample(letters, 1000,replace = T ),
                 sample(letters, 1000,replace = T ),
                 sample(letters, 1000,replace = T ),
                 sample(letters, 1000,replace = T ),
                 sample(6000:7000, 1000, replace = T )))
```

Here I will use the `str_remove` function to remove the numbers (\d+) after the last colon (:) using the "$" to indicate the end of the string. Count will also pull each unique and the column "n" will indicate how many times it will appear.

```
# Libraries
library(tidyverse)
randz %>% 
  mutate(out = str_remove(string = id,
                           pattern = ":\\d+$")) %>% 
  count(out,sort = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
A tibble: 1,000 x 2
   out                    n
   <chr>              <int>
 1 identifier:aar:muk     1
 2 identifier:abe:tlo     1
 3 identifier:abg:qux     1
 4 identifier:abh:bxx     1
 5 identifier:abl:vdj     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract them using regex. Here's an example using the `stringr` package.

```r
str_extract("identifier:de:ghijklm:RANDOMNUMBERSTRING", "(identifier\\:[a-z]+\\:[a-z]+)")
```